# Getting Firebase Cloud Messaging token in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to react native and I am trying to create an app that has background notifications. After doing some research I feel the best way to do this would be to use firebase cloud messaging.

After following a number of different tutorials I have written the following code.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component { 
  requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
      if (enabled) {
        getFcmToken();
        console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
      }
    };

    getFcmToken = async () => {
      const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
      if (fcmToken) {
          console.log(fcmToken);
          console.log("Your Firebase Token is:", fcmToken);
      } else {
          console.log("Failed", "No Token Recived");
      }
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
      await this.requestUserPermission();

       // Register background handler
       messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
       console.log('Messaage handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  });
};
  }
```

When I run my app on my iOS device I can see within the terminal that I get the following error.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getFcmToken

When I try to send a test message it doesn't seem to appear.

My question is: Am I writing my code incorrectly or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `getFcmToken` before you actually use it.

```
    // declare getFcmToken first
    const getFcmToken = async () => {
      const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
      if (fcmToken) {
          console.log(fcmToken);
          console.log("Your Firebase Token is:", fcmToken);
      } else {
          console.log("Failed", "No Token Recived");
      }
    };

    // then use it
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
      if (enabled) {
        getFcmToken();
        console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
      }
    };
```

Comment: this is what I had thought of doing but it seems to cause a syntax error

Comment: once I placed the token function outside of the app component I seemed to work. Thanks for your help